# Deeply nested transaction writes with Prisma

Tags: node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js, prisma

One of the advantages of Sequelize is its ability to just pass in a already structured request.body with nested relations data using `includes` and it'll create the relationship for you or use Mixins.

I have been using `Prisma` for a month now and currently i am trying to do transactions with `Nested Writes` , and i am finding it hard to accomplish.

I would have posted my question here, but it is too long.

Because atm i have to pull apart and build each property from the request.Body and pass it into the `create` for every relationship when creating with deeply nested writes.

Doing it this way, can lead to creating wrong relationships when creating.

What i want to ask is how to accomplish Nested Writes similar to Sequelize's includes? and also

Can someone please help with how they accomplish `DEEPLY` (like 3 or 4 levels) nested writes ?

Comment: Before I can answer your question. Have you gone through the [Prisma transaction guide](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/prisma-client-transactions-guide/) ? Also would be easy if you can provide a scenario where you are struggling.

Comment: Prisma supports nested writes with the ```Create``` and ```connectOrCreate``` API. You should check out the [nested write section](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#nested-writes) for more details. Additionally, as pointed out, an example would help clarify your problem better.

Comment: Hi @PasinduDilshan, i have found my answer, got a hint from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68151867/prisma-upsertmany-issue-provided-listjson-expected-similarcreatewithoutmoviei

Apparently Prisma can't take a multiple level nested object relation like sequelize.
You will have to use a create/createMany/connectOrCreate property after the second level.

Got an explanation here https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/8637#discussioncomment-1147612

that i have to transform my request body to the format Prisma accepts

Comment: Hi @TasinIshmam, i have gotten my answer....see above comment

Comment: Great, good to know!

Answer (score 2):

For anyone landing here searching for how to work with deeply nested relations (like me!), there is an example at [Prisma.io](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#create-a-single-record-and-multiple-related-records) that I missed that shows how to do deeply nested reads and writes (nest the `includes` and `create` keys respectively):

```
const user = await prisma.user.create({
  data: {
    email: 'yvette@prisma.io',
    name: 'Yvette',
    posts: {
      create: [
        {
          title: 'How to make an omelette',
          categories: {
            create: {
              name: 'Easy cooking',
            },
          },
        },
        { title: 'How to eat an omelette' },
      ],
    },
  },
  include: {
    // Include posts
    posts: {
      include: {
        categories: true, // Include post categories
      },
    },
  },
})
```